# Объявление указателей через запятую

Tags: c++, c, указатели

Данное предложение объявляет два указателя или указатель и объект? Верно ли это для любого типа переменных?

`int* x, y;`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`int* x, y;` - указатель `x` и целочисленная переменная `y`.

`*` относится к *переменной*, а не к *типу*.

Объявите тип с помощью `typedef` (или в C++ - с помощью `using`) - тогда дело другое:

```
typedef int * pint;
pint x, y;
```

Здесь и `x`, и `y` - указатели на `int`.

Comment: Никогда не делайте так `typedef int * pint;` в C.

Comment: @0andriy <irony_mode>Win API с вами не согласно!</irony_mode>

Comment: @0andriy Поделитесь тогда, как это нужно делать.

Comment: @0andriy, почему? Вот про define помню, а тут-то что не так?

Comment: @Harry, использовать явно. Это имеет смысл для *opaque pointers*, для POD это делает код подверженны ошибкам (помним к примеру, что неявный кастинг `type *` в `void *` работает), квалификатор const с этим плох. Можно почитать http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781932 с комментариями и ответами, потом по ссылке там же.

Comment: @0andriy С тем же учпехом можно написать - не объявляйте в одной строке и переменную типа, и переменную-указатель...  Все зависит от того, как и для чего это делать. С другой стороны, лично я typedef'ы использовал в основном для сложных сигнатур функций :)

Answer (score 1):

Указатель и не указатель.
Поэтому звёздочку и принято писать перед именем переменной, а не перед типом.

http://ideone.com/oVvCU2

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    short *a, b;
    printf("%zu %zu\n", sizeof a, sizeof b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Кем принято????

Comment: @alexolut, всеми?)

Comment: отнюдь. Принято вовсе писать каждый идентификатор на новой строке с типом.

Comment: @alexolut, во-первых, одно другому не мешает - вполне можно писать по одному объявлению на строке и при этом ставить звёздочку перед именем. А во-вторых, я бы поспорил, что действительно принято писать по одному на строке.

Comment: поспорьте :) но лучше в чате