# Как ставится звездочка при создании указателя в си?

Tags: c, указатели

Как ставится звездочка `*` при создании указателя? Точнее в чем разница между:

- `char* str;`
- `char * str;`
- `char *str;`

На что влияет место в котором находится `*`?

Comment: Связанный вопрос (или дубликат, хз) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/625271

Comment: Вы забыли беспробельный `char*str` :)

Answer (score 10):

Пробельные символы допустимо ставить в любом месте, где он не разрывает ключевое слово, идентификатор или константу.

Все варианты ниже полностью эквивалентны:

```
char*str;
char*str ;
char* str;
char *str;
char* str ;
char *str ;
char * str;
char * str ;
```

Но есть некоторая тонкость. Если посмотреть на синтаксис объявления нескольких переменных:

```
char * str1, * str2, c3, * p4, c5; // str1, str2 и p4 - указатели, c3 и c5 - символы
```

то будет видно, что "звездочка" является скорее модификатором переменной, чем модификатором типа. Чтобы подчеркнуть этот факт, рекомендуется всегда писать "звездочку" около переменной. Такая привычка позволяет избежать глупых ошибок:

```
char *str1, *str2; // нормально
char* str1, str2; // Ошибка: str2 кажется строкой, но на самом деле - символ.
```

Answer (score 5):

Ни на что не влияет. Но есть подводный камень:

```
char* str1, str2;
```

В этом примере только str1 является указателем. str2 - просто char. Поэтому я обычно делаю так:

```
char *str1, *str2;
```

Теперь обе переменные являются указателями.

Comment: То есть, место постановки звездочки не влияет? И все три примера сделают одно и то же?

Comment: @FiLCh, да, все три ваших примера делают одно и то же.