# invalid conversion from ‘const char’ to ‘char’

Tags: c++

Есть такое определение (расположено вне функций):

```
struct {
    const char* completion = "----TEST COMPLETED----",
    speed = "Average typing speed",
    speed_mod = "wpm",
    accuracy = "Average accuracy",
    work_harder = "Work harder for your accuracy!",
    not_bad = "Not bad, but you can get it with better accuracy!",
    excellent = "Excellent! Now, you can try to work with your speed.",
    question_records = "Do you want to save your records?",
    yes = "Yes",
    no = "No",
    question_name = "Enter your name",
    players_records = "----RECORDS----",
    bye = "Goodbye!";
} messages;
```

Компилятор здесь выдает *error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘*char*', указывая на каждый литерал. Мне непонятно, что он имеет ввиду.
В чем некорректен этот код?

Comment: Звёздочка здесь `const char*` относится только к полю `completion`. Остальные поля имеют тип `const char`. Соответственно, инициализировать их строковыми литералами нельзя. Можно использовать дополнительные звёздочки возле каждого поля, чтобы объявить их указателями `const char *completion = "---", *speed = "---";` См. [Объявление указателей через запятую](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/625271).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В С/С++ при объявлении указателя `*` относится *не к типу*, а к *переменной*, т.е. `type * a` рассматривается как `type (*a)`, а не `(type*) a`, а потому эту звездочку надо указывать у каждого члена:

```
struct {
    const char* completion = "----TEST COMPLETED----",
    *speed = "Average typing speed",
    *speed_mod = "wpm",
    ....
} messages;
```

Или объявить *тип* с помощью `typedef` или `using` и использовать его, например:

```
struct {
    using ccptr = const char*; // Или typedef const char* ccptr;
    ccptr completion = "----TEST COMPLETED----",
    speed = "Average typing speed",
    speed_mod = "wpm",
    ....
} messages;
```